# Minecraft 1.10 Survival - Wheat Problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have built an underground farm, but whenever I place wheat seeds next to each other on wet farmland, the wheat blocks break and the wheat seeds drop on the ground.

Could anyone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description it sounds like you do not have a strong enough light source. Simple tourches should suffice.

This article here (https://levelskip.com/simulation/How-to-Build-an-Underground-Farm-in-Minecraft) states:

> Wheat, carrots, potatoes and other crops like melons and pumpkins can grow as long as the light level above them is at least 9 - it does not have to be sunlight. Torches alone have a light level of 14!

and if that level is not supplied:

> Instead of harvesting each crop block by block, you can set up a light system controlled by redstone. Since crops need a light source to grow, you can arrange your underground farm so that the flip of a lever will turn off the lights and make the crops pop out of the ground.

Your crops will not even plant! Hope I was able to help.

Comment: Yup!  Thanks a lot!  I'm suprised I didn't think of that!

Comment: Not a problem, always happy to help